# How to map array of values to array of objects in IBM API management?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

As a part of composite api, I need to do following mapping in IBM API management

Request JSON

```
{
   "groupName": "string",
   "notes": "string",
   "Goal_Description": "string",
   "Goal_Date": "string",
   "Goal_Target": "string",
   "Goal_Contribution": "string"
}
```

While calling API, this needs to be mapped to

```
{
   "group": {
      "groupName": "string",
      "notes": "string"
   },
   "customInformation": [
      {
         "value": "NA",
         "customFieldID": "Goal_Description"
      },
      {
         "value": "NA",
         "customFieldID": "Goal_Date"
      },
      {
         "value": "NA",
         "customFieldID": "Goal_Target"
      },
      {
         "value": "NA",
         "customFieldID": "Goal_Contribution"
      }
   ]
}
```

When trying to map in API management portal, 'customInformation' is represented as an array of objects and I cannot map individual values to array on objects.

[Attributes mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5YGD.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I checked with my colleagues and as of now, there is no ability to do the mapping more than one attribute to an array object.  I do not have a suggestion either.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I also opened a support ticket and this sort of mapping is not possible in api management service